# Chromium (Chrome, Brave) on mobile stopped trusting my local LetsEncrypt certificates

Tags: ssl, local, chromium, lets-encrypt

I have registered a wildcard certificate for `*.dev.example.com` which I use on my locally installed nginx server, to serve websites and to be able to test them on all devices, Android, iOS, etc...

The workflow is as follow (briefly)

- The routers `dnsmasq` is configured to route all `*.dev.example.com` requests to `192.168.1.xxx`
- `192.168.1.xxx` runs nginx, which is configured to use the wildcard certificates for `*.dev.example.com`
- Accessing `https://dev.example.com` and `https://xxx.dev.example.com` from any device within the LAN worked without problems.

Now, since of today, Google (Brave) are denying the certificate and won't request the URL properly -> nginx returns `File not found`

If I call the URL from an Android REST-client (like Restler), or Firefox or Opera, everything works as expected.

Has anything changed in Chromium regarding this manner?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that Brave had `Use secure DNS` enabled (maybe through a recent update), which circumvented my router's DNS settings.